# How to obtain array back from req.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sending an array of objects to Node.js server. After receiving on req.body, I am getting as Object with a single key containing all the objects from the array.

I have tried to few ways like iterating the object, it returns single key. Also tried JSON.parse(), but it is a string already.

As well as string.split(",") but it looks complicated and inefficient.

```
/* Sent from client */
var names = [{
    "firstName" : "Darshak",
    "lastName" : "Mehta"
  },{
    "firstName" : "Russell",
    "lastName" : "Peters"
  }];


/* Obtained following at server in req.body */ 
const y = { '{"firstName":"Darshak","lastName":"Mehta"},
{"firstName" : "Russell","lastName" : "Peters"}': '' }
```

**EDIT**

*CLIENT*

```
await this.add([{
    "firstName" : "Darshak",
    "lastName" : "Mehta"
  },{
    "firstName" : "Russell",
    "lastName" : "Peters"
  }]);

add = (data) => {
    var config = {
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
 };
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/data', data, config)
      .then((res) => {
        /* Successful message */
      })
      .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

*SERVER*

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
const app = express();

app.post('/data', urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(typeof Object.keys(req.body)[0]); /* Outputs String */
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I am trying to get the names array back.

Comment: Can you please do a ```console.log(req.body);``` on the server and post the result here.

Comment: { '{"firstName":"Darshak","lastName":"Mehta"},
{"firstName" : "Russell","lastName" : "Peters"}': '' }

This is what I have received on console.log

Answer (score 2):

Update your data object before sending

`CLIENT`

```
await this.add([{
    "firstName": "Darshak",
    "lastName": "Mehta"
}, {
    "firstName": "Russell",
    "lastName": "Peters"
}]);
add = (data) => {
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    var userArray = {
        userArray: data
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/data', userArray, config)
        .then((res) => {
            /* Successful message */
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

now get userArray from req.body
`server`

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.userArray);
});
```

Comment: Why did you remove urlencodedParser from app.post()?

Comment: I tried this earlier, received



{ '{"userArray":[{"firstName":"Darshak","lastName":"Mehta"},{"firstName":"Russell","lastName":"Peters"}]}': '' }

On trying to access it gives undefined.? Do I have to get rid of single quotes?

Comment: you can use `JSON.parse` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

This object is not serialized/stringified properly. In this request string, there is only one key ({"firstName":"Darshak","lastName":"Mehta"},
{"firstName" : "Russell","lastName" : "Peters"}) whose value is an empty string. This should be fixed from the requesting system. It should have been serialized something like this:

```
"[{"firstName":"Darshak","lastName":"Mehta"},
{"firstName" : "Russell","lastName" : "Peters"}]"
```

.

Comment: When I try to JSON.stringify(names), it gives the above array. I agree it should give me the one you have mentioned although not getting the quotes.

Comment: This should be fixed from the system which requests your node server. There is no sane way you can workaround this. You can use something like this - var correctBody = null;
for(var key in req.body){
 correctBody = JSON.parse(key);
}
console.log(correctBody); correctBody is now the request body that you were expecting. And there might still be issues - like I said, no sane way :/